# Where does the dirname/basename terminology originate?

Tags: path, standards, dirname

1. What are the origins and reasons for the terms, `dirname` and `basename`, referring to the path with the trailing component removed, and the trailing component respectively?
2. Is the terminology standardized, and where?
3. Are there alternative or equivalent conventions in use to refer to the splitting of a path in this way?

### Update0

In particular, alternatives used on major operating systems or libraries are of interest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The terms `dirname` and `basename` seem quite straightforward, i.e. "directory name" and "base name within the directory", so I don't think there is any specific reason for these names.

I'm not sure what you mean by "Is the terminology standardized". The calls are part of the POSIX standard ([dirname](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/dirname.html), [basename](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/basename.html)) but they've also been borrowed by many high-level languages like PHP ([dirname](http://php.net/manual/en/function.dirname.php), [basename](http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php)), [Perl](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Basename.html) and [Python](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html).

**Other equivalents:**

On Windows, the shell API provides the [`PathRemoveFileSpec`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773748%28VS.85%29.aspx) and [`PathStripPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773756%28VS.85%29.aspx) functions, which are similar to `dirname` and `basename`.

In Java, the [File](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html) class provides `getParent` and `getName` which do the same thing.

Comment: Can you link to the relevant examples in POSIX and PHP?

Comment: Done, also added Perl, Python and Java.

Comment: Long before the functions were standardized, the utilities [dirname](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/dirname.html) and [basename](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/basename.html) were available - [Version 7 UNIX](http://plan9.bell-labs.com/7thEdMan/) had the utilities, but not the functions, for instance.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffer: Thanks for the references. I guessed but wasn't sure that they originated somewhere in UNIX.

Comment: (Oops: it appears that `dirname`, the command, was not in V7 UNIX after all, though `basename` was, essentially the same as now defined in POSIX.)